# Passing an argument by reference with reflection

Tags: php, reflection, pass-by-reference

[This article](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-3-testing-protected-private-methods-coverage-reports-and-crap/#targeting-private%2Fprotected-methods-directly) has the following method:

```
/**
 * Call protected/private method of a class.
 *
 * @param object &$object    Instantiated object that we will run method on.
 * @param string $methodName Method name to call
 * @param array  $parameters Array of parameters to pass into method.
 *
 * @return mixed Method return.
 */
public function invokeMethod(&$object, $methodName, array $parameters = array())
{
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
    $method = $reflection->getMethod($methodName);
    $method->setAccessible(true);

    return $method->invokeArgs($object, $parameters);
}
```

My question is...  is there a particular reason why `$object` has an ampersand before it in the function declaration? Normally that'd mean you were passing by reference but doens't PHP pass objects by reference by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) section of the  PHP documentation:

> PHP supports passing arguments by value (the default), passing by reference, and default argument values. Variable-length argument lists are also supported.

By default, arguments are passed by value.

As for objects, it may seem that they are passed by reference but that is not totally true. See [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) which states:

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an **object identifier** which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

So, to avoid confusion, I would always assume that the parameter is NOT passed by value, even for an object.  If you want it to be passed by reference, add the `&` to make sure you are really passing it by reference.

Here is an example with an object:

```
<?php

// Passed by value... won't be affected
function byValue($arg) { 
  $arg = null;
} 

// Passed by reference... will be affected
function byReference(&$arg) { 
  $arg = null;
} 

$obj = new StdClass;
var_dump($obj);  // Untouched object created

byValue($obj);
var_dump($obj);  // After 'trying' to set it to null

byReference($obj);
var_dump($obj);  // After setting it to null for real
```

<kbd>[**Run demo**](https://eval.in/712489)</kbd>

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9M5nEheS seems like it's passing by reference to me.

Comment: I edited my answer to cover the "objects reference". :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you think you could come up with an example where invokeMethod will behave differently when a ampersand is present vs when one is not? That'd really help me visualize it. Thanks!

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is... is there a particular reason why $object has an
>   ampersand before it in the function declaration?

In this piece of code, **no**. `$object` is only used for its value inside this function. The only two places where it is used are to be passed to `get_class()` (which takes its argument by value), and to be passed to `ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs()` (which also takes its arguments by value).

Therefore, there was no point to take `$object` by reference.